# Vertex AI Endpoint creation failes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When I try to deploy a google auto ml trained model to a google vertex ai endpoint (which worked 3 days ago) I suddely get an error message:

Hello Vertex AI Customer,

Due to an error, Vertex AI was unable to create endpoint "test2".
Additional Details:
Operation State: Failed with errors
Resource Name:
projects//######/locations/europe-west4/endpoints//#####
Error Messages: Machine type temporarily unavailable, please deploy with a
different machine type or retry

To view the error on Cloud Console, go back to your endpoint using
https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/locations/europe-west4/models//#####/versions/1/deploy?authuser=1&folder=&organizationId=&project=/######

Sincerely,
The Google Cloud AI TeamHello Vertex AI Customer,

Does anyone have an idea why the endpoint deployment suddely does not work anymore?

Comment: The error includes "Machine type temporarily unavailable, please deploy with a different machine type or retry". I suspect that there are insufficient resources of the machine type that you're using in the zone|region where you're trying to use it. As the error suggests, if you're willing to try a different machine type, you may be successful. Alternatively, wait until resources of your preferred machine type become available.

Comment: Could you talk more about your machine type and the specs of your endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I learned the hard way that `europe-west4` has strange limitations for prediction. For example, if you check this [Region Considerations](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/locations#region_considerations) page, you'll see that some `europe-west4` accelerators are used for training but not prediction.

Otherwise, if you say it worked three days ago, it could be due to pressure on resources in `europe-west4` (which is very common to use with Vertex AI due to its wider range of available resources for training and prediction).